# How to select min value from each bin after binning the dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, binning

I have a dataframe and I have divided the dataframe into bins of equal width.

```
bins = np.linspace(pc13.pc1.min(), pc13.pc1.max(), 10)

pc13_bins_temp = np.array_split(pc13, 10)
```

Now I want to select min value from each bin, and add that to new dataframe.

Comment: Would you like show your dataframe ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `left`

```
pd.cut(df['Yourvalue'],5).apply(lambda x : x.left)
Out[57]: 
0     290.414
1     290.414
2    1011.200
3    1011.200
4    3162.800
5    3162.800
Name: pass, dtype: category
Categories (5, float64): [290.414 < 1011.200 < 1728.400 < 2445.600 < 3162.800]
```

Comment: This is giving me the same dataframe it is not dividing into bins. The approach which I tried is working but I don't know how can I select min value from each bin

Comment: @piRSquared just change the name haha

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this for getting smallest values from each bin.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df1 = df.append([df[i].min()], ignore_index=True)
```